# Connection to AWS SES on prot 465 Timed Out Error

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, digital-ocean, amazon-ses

Switching mail provider to AWS on a laravel app hosted on digitalocean but keep getting this error

> Connection to tcp://email-smtp.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com:465 Timed Out

I have verified the domain name, created an IAM users and sent a test email from the aws console to gmail which delivered successfully.

But still unable to send from the app on digitalocean. What am I missing right now?

Comment: Firewall? Port blocked? Proxy? Sounds more like a network related issue really.

Comment: I think so too, any suggestions @HonkderHase